# JSX Item type does not exist in visual studio 2013

Tags: json, reactjs, visual-studio, jsx

I am going to build a react application and then I need a JSX file type, when I have to add new item from visual studio 2013 I don't have a type of JSX file. How can I get it ? and the same problem in JSON type files.

Comment: Honestly, you're better of using Visual Studio Code for React development, instead of full Visual Studio, especially that version. VS Code is free, has full support for modern code linting and intellisense, and it's smaller and faster: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Install ReactJS starter kit from Visual studio market place

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KonstantinTarkus.ReactjsStarterKit